# Gembox Document HTML to PDF doesn't show the text vertically

Tags: c#, html, css, pdf, gembox-document

While converting from HTML to PDF, I noticed that Gembox Document doesn't recognize the "REPRINT" strings as a vertical.
The following is the HTML code:

```html
<html>

  <head>
    <style>
      .main-container {
        text-align: center;
      }
      
      .code {
        font-size: 25px;
        font-weight: bold;
        letter-spacing: 1px;
      }


      .mrg-btm {
        margin-bottom: 8px;
      }


      .name-and-code {
        font-size: 24px;
        font-weight: bold;
        letter-spacing: 3px;
      }


      .font-bold {
        font-weight: bold;
      }

    
      .table-class {
        width: 100%;
        font-size: 14px;
      }

    
      td {
        width: 50%;
      }

    
      .line-left {
        text-align: left;
      }

    
      .line-right {
        text-align: right;
      }


      .scadenza {
        font-size: 24px;
        font-weight: bold;
        letter-spacing: 3px;
      }


      .data-scadenza {
        font-size: 24px;
        font-weight: bold;
        letter-spacing: 2px;
      }


      .materiali {
        font-size: 24px;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-align: left;
        letter-spacing: 5px;
      }


      .last-codes {
        font-size: 10px;
        text-align: left;
      }


      .mrg-btm-two {
        margin-bottom: 64px;
      }


      .mrg-btm-three {
        margin-bottom: 16px;
      }
      
      
      .mrg-btm-four {
        margin-bottom: 20px;
      }

      .mrg-side-left {
        margin-left: 2px;
      }

      .main-table {
        width: 100%;
      }

      .reprint-td {
        width: 5%;
        writing-mode: vertical-lr;
        text-align: center;
        letter-spacing: 4px;
        font-size: 18px;
        font-weight: bold;
      }

      .main-td {
        width: 90%;
      }
      
      .reprint-div {
        display: inline-block;
        height: 100%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>


  <body>
       
    <table class="main-table">
       <tr>
          <td class="reprint-td">
            <div class="reprint-div">REPRINT</div>
          </td>
            
          <td class="main-td">
            <div class="main-container">
  
               <div class="code mrg-btm">
                  <label>__LABEL1__</label>
               </div>
    
    
               <div class="name-and-code mrg-btm-four">
                  <label>__LABEL2__&nbsp;&nbsp;__LABEL3__</label>
               </div> 
    
    
               <div class="mrg-btm-four"> 
                  <img alt='Barcode Generator TEC-IT' src='https://barcode.tec-it.com/barcode.ashx?data=BARCODE_NUMBER&code=Code39'/>
               </div>

    
               <div class="mrg-btm-three">
                  <table class="table-class">
                     <tr>
                        <td class="line-left">SQA_TEXT</td>
                        <td class="font-bold line-right">METER</td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td class="line-left">GOMSET</td>
                        <td class="line-right">FIRST_DATA</td>
                     </tr>
                  </table>
               </div>
  
  
               <div class="scadenza mrg-btm">
                  <label>EXPIRE_TEXT</label>
               </div>


               <div class="data-scadenza mrg-btm">
                  <label>EXPIRE_DATA</label>
               </div>
  
  
               <div class="materiali mrg-btm">
                  <label>MATERIALS_TEXT</label>
               </div>
  
  
               <div class="last-codes mrg-btm-two">
                  <label class="mrg-side-left">RC_NUMBER&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;AFTER_RC</label>
               </div>
  
  
               <div class="last-codes mrg-btm">
                  <label class="mrg-side-left">SB_CODE&nbsp;&nbsp;STR_CODE&nbsp;&nbsp;SECOND_DATA</label>
               </div>
  
  
               <div class="last-codes">
                  <label class="mrg-side-left">C_CODE_NUMBER&nbsp;&nbsp;RC_NUMBER&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;AFTER_RC</label>
               </div> 
  
            </div> 
          </td>
          
          <td class="reprint-td">
             <div class="reprint-div">REPRINT</div>
          </td>
       </tr>
    </table>
    
  </body>
  
</html>
```

The following is the result of the HTML code (it is ok):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJveC.jpg)

The following are the C# methods of our interest:

```js
private void convertHtmlToPdf(string filenameHtml)
        {
            showMessage("Operation in progress...");
            string realHtml = replaceIntoTemplate(File.ReadAllText(filenameHtml));
            File.WriteAllText(path + htmlFilenameReplaced, realHtml);
            GemBox.Document.ComponentInfo.SetLicense(licenseGemboxDocument);
            DocumentModel document = DocumentModel.Load(path + htmlFilenameReplaced);
            document.DefaultCharacterFormat.FontName = "Verdana";
            GemBox.Document.Section section = document.Sections[0];
            PageSetup pageSetup = section.PageSetup;
            pageSetup.PageWidth = 383.62;
            pageSetup.PageHeight = 576.95;
            PageMargins pageMargins = pageSetup.PageMargins;
            pageMargins.Top = pageMargins.Bottom = 96;
            pageMargins.Left = pageMargins.Right = 48;           
            document.Save(path + pdfFilename);
            showMessage("Successfully conversion HTML to PDF");
        }
```

```js
private string replaceIntoTemplate(string templateHtml)
        {
            string newTemplateHtml = templateHtml;
            newTemplateHtml = newTemplateHtml.Replace("__LABEL1__", label1.Replace(" ", "&nbsp;"));
            newTemplateHtml = newTemplateHtml.Replace("__LABEL2__", label2.Replace(" ", "&nbsp;"));
            newTemplateHtml = newTemplateHtml.Replace("__LABEL3__", label3.Replace(" ", "&nbsp;"));
            newTemplateHtml = newTemplateHtml.Replace("BARCODE_NUMBER", barcode.Replace(" ", "&nbsp;"));
            newTemplateHtml = newTemplateHtml.Replace("SQA_TEXT", sqa.Replace(" ", "&nbsp;"));
            newTemplateHtml = newTemplateHtml.Replace("METER", meter.Replace(" ", "&nbsp;"));
            newTemplateHtml = newTemplateHtml.Replace("GOMSET", gomset.Replace(" ", "&nbsp;"));
            newTemplateHtml = newTemplateHtml.Replace("FIRST_DATA", firstData.Replace(" ", "&nbsp;"));
            newTemplateHtml = newTemplateHtml.Replace("EXPIRE_TEXT", expireText.Replace(" ", "&nbsp;"));
            newTemplateHtml = newTemplateHtml.Replace("EXPIRE_DATA", expireData.Replace(" ", "&nbsp;"));
            newTemplateHtml = newTemplateHtml.Replace("MATERIALS_TEXT", materials.Replace(" ", "&nbsp;"));
            newTemplateHtml = newTemplateHtml.Replace("RC_NUMBER", rcNumber.Replace(" ", "&nbsp;"));
            newTemplateHtml = newTemplateHtml.Replace("AFTER_RC", numberAfterRc.Replace(" ", "&nbsp;"));
            newTemplateHtml = newTemplateHtml.Replace("SB_CODE", sbCode.Replace(" ", "&nbsp;"));
            newTemplateHtml = newTemplateHtml.Replace("STR_CODE", strCode.Replace(" ", "&nbsp;"));
            newTemplateHtml = newTemplateHtml.Replace("SECOND_DATA", secondData.Replace(" ", "&nbsp;"));
            newTemplateHtml = newTemplateHtml.Replace("C_CODE_NUMBER", cCode.Replace(" ", "&nbsp;"));
            return newTemplateHtml;
        }
```

The result of the conversion from HTML to PDF is the following (with the "REPRINT" strings not vertically):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4LwD.jpg)

What can I change in the convertHtmlToPdf C# method for obtained the "REPRINT" strings vertically?

Answer (score 1):

Try using this latest bugfix version:
https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/document/nightlybuilds/GBD35v1134.zip

Or this latest NuGet package:
`Install-Package GemBox.Document -Version 35.0.1134-hotfix`

The `writing-mode` CSS property in table cells should now be supported.